# How do I filter for data that has partially matching pairs using filter and str_detect in R?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, stringr

I am trying to filter for data that has matching groups, and if they do not have one, I want to remove those observations.

For example, if I have a dataset:

```
#  condition   group     type
#1   apple_1       B    small
#2   apple_1       A    small
#3   apple 1       A    small
#4   apple_2       A    small
#5   apple_2       A    small
#6   apple_3       A    small
#7    pear_1       A    small
#8    pear_1       A    small
#9    pear_1       A    small
#10   pear_2       A    small
#11   pear_3       A    small
```

Here I decided that each apple observation must pair up to each pair observation by their number (ex. apple_3 should pair up with pear_3). So we can see that since there's only one pear_2 observation, one of the apple_2 observation should be removed since there are two apple_2 observations. Also, since the first apple_1 is in group B, therefore not matching to any pears, apple_1 with group B should be removed, and a pear_1 observation should be removed since it does not have a matching pair.

The problem here is that the observations are named using underscores, so I need to somehow manipulate `str_detect` and groups need to match so I need to use `filter` as well. I feel like this type of filtering could be done using `dplyr`, but I'm not sure.

The expected result should be: The expected result I'm looking for is something like this:

```
#  condition   group     type
#1   apple_1       A    small
#2   apple_1       A    small
#3   apple_2       A    small
#4   apple_3       A    small
#5    pear_1       A    small
#6    pear_1       A    small
#7    pear_2       A    small
#8    pear_3       A    small
```

so that each of the apple with a specific number has a matching pear with the same number.

Comment: Why not use `strsplit` to create a new variable with the suffix 1,2,3 after the underscore in `condition`?

Comment: Hi Eric welcome to SO. Can you provide an example of what is your expected result? Also, I think you have missed and underscore in you 3 row (I believe it should be apple_1)

Comment: Okay, I'll try using `strsplit` and see where it goes. Thank you.

Comment: within `tidyverse` you will also find `tidyr::separate` for this purpose.

Comment: Great, I'll explore using `tidyverse` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
vec_drop <- function(x){
  b <- table(x)
  if(length(b)<2) return(FALSE)
  a <- split(!logical(length(x)), x)
  if (length(unique(b))>1)
    a[[names(which.max(b))]][seq(abs(diff(b)))] <- FALSE
  unsplit(a, x)
}


df %>%
  group_by(group, cond = str_remove(condition, "\\w+_"))%>%
  filter(vec_drop(condition))


condition group type  cond 
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 apple_1   A     small 1    
2 apple_1   A     small 1    
3 apple_2   A     small 2    
4 apple_3   A     small 3    
5 pear_1    A     small 1    
6 pear_1    A     small 1    
7 pear_2    A     small 2    
8 pear_3    A     small 3    
>
```